# How to get time x days ago from a specific date in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking for a rails solution to calculate the time ago from a particulat time. For example , 2 days ago 15th May 2016 22:00 UTC should return 13th May 2016 22::00 UTC .

My requirement is something like this

```
2.days.ago.from(yesterday)
```

Which will be a more specific version of

```
2.days.from_now
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
> DateTime.now-2.days
=> Wed, 18 May 2016 21:40:31 -0700
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I do not want time  ago in words. This will output something like " 2 Hours Ago" , What I am trying to find is the exact time ago 2 days from  a specific time.

Comment: Yes but I got a more specific solution

2.days.ago(time = my_time)

Answer (score 5):

how about this:

```
# 2 days before a specific date
specific_date.days_ago(2)
```

Example:

```
specific_date                   = DateTime.now
two_days_ago_from_specific_date = specific_date.days_ago(2)
```

Answer (score 4):

My personal favorite syntax for this with rails would be

```
x.days.ago
```

For example, if you wanted 10 days ago you would call

```
10.days.ago
=> Sat, 12 Feb 2022 01:36:58 UTC +00:00
```

Easy to read and defaults to UTC.